# Keys of nested map loaded with ConfigurationProperties are prefixed with their respective indexes

Tags: java, spring-boot, dictionary

With spring boot I'm trying to load configuration using the annotation **@ConfigurationProperties("oauth2.discovery")**.

Everything works fine except the fact that keys of a nested map are not loaded with the configuration file content but instead they are prefixed with their respectiveindexes.

This is the code used to load the configuration :

```
@ConfigurationProperties("oauth2.discovery")
public class DiscoveryConfigs {

    private Map<String, DiscoveryConfigs.DiscoveryConfig> config;

    public Map<String, DiscoveryConfigs.DiscoveryConfig> getConfig() {
        return this.config;
    }

    public void setConfig(Map<String, DiscoveryConfigs.DiscoveryConfig> discovery) {
        this.config = discovery;
    }

    public static class DiscoveryConfig {
        private String name;
        private Map<String, String> endpoints;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getEndpoints() {
            return endpoints;
        }

        public void setEndpoints(Map<String, String> endpoints) {
            this.endpoints = endpoints;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my **application.yml**

```
oauth2:
  discovery:
    config:
      affiliation:
        name: affiliation-service
        endpoints:
          - public: /getPublic
          - forRoleA: /getForRoleA
          - forRoleB: /getForRoleB
      blabla:
        name: ...
```

And using **DiscoveryConfigs**  to load the **application.yml** I got the following content:

> ( debugger view in IntellIj )
> endpoints = {LinkedHashMap@10957}  size > = 3
> "0.public" -> "/getPublic"
> "1.forRoleA" -> "/getForRoleA"
> "2.forRoleB" -> "/getForRoleB"

Where keys are for example **"0.public"** instead of **"public"**

So I'm sure I missed something but I cannot figure what...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the description to [Binding Maps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding-maps) on spring.io. The following should work:

```
oauth2:
  discovery:
    config:
      affiliation:
        name: affiliation-service
        endpoints:
          public: /getPublic
          forRoleA: /getForRoleA
          forRoleB: /getForRoleB
```